# Boolean Expression AND Gate Java

Tags: java, boolean, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

Hi I have a code that when you input an expression it will store to an array but my problem is how can i put * between two variables when the input expression is like ab +c?it says null value.
here's my code:

```
 stack = strexp.toCharArray();       
 for (int k = 0; k < stack.length; k++) {
   if (Character.isLetter(stack[k]) && Character.isLetter(stack[k+1])){
     temp[k] = stack[k];
     temp[k+1] = '*';
     temp[k+2] = stack[k+1];
   }
 }
```

Comment: This is really unclear as written.  Also, is it homework?

Comment: sir when i run the code there's an error saying nullpointerexception. for example the inputted expression is ab+c. when this expression will be stored in an array it will become a*b+c. it is not a homework sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should receive an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception, because you increment `k` until it is equal to the last index in the `stack` array and *then* you try to access `stack[k+1]`.

Your loop expression has to be

```
for (int k = 0; k < (stack.length-1); k++)
```

The cause of the `NullPointerException` is not directly visible but I believe that you haven't initialized the `temp` array. Most likely because you do not know it's exact size.

I'd store the result in a <strike>list</strike> StringBuilder instead:

```
StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (int k = 0; k < (stack.length-1); k++) {
   resultBuilder.append(stack[k]);
   if (Character.isLetter(stack[k]) && Character.isLetter(stack[k+1])) {
     resultBuilder.append('*');
  }
}
resultBuilder.append(stack[stack.length-1]);  // don't forget the last element
```

Comment: I'm tempted to suggest using a `StringBuilder` instead of an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues:

1) NPE - Will be resolved by intializing the `temp[]`

2) ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at `Character.isLetter(stack[k + 1])`

Use this code to resolve both:

```
    String strexp = "ab+c";
    char[] stack = strexp.toCharArray();
    for (int k = 0; k < stack.length - 1; k++)
    {
        if (Character.isLetter(stack[k]) && Character.isLetter(stack[k + 1]))
        {
            char temp[] = new char[3];
            temp[k] = stack[k];
            temp[k + 1] = '*';
            temp[k + 2] = stack[k + 1];
        }
    }
```